# Is there an equivalent to Symfony's Localized Schema in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localization, internationalization, symfony1

I've been searching for an equivalent to Symfony's built-in Localized Schema which provides a native support for managing internationalized Tables/DB. Here is a link to Symfony's [documentation covering their implementation of I18n & L10n](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/13-I18n-and-L10n), with the relevant part on Localized Schema (appx. a third down the page, such as the paragraph "Text Information in the Database").

I've checked out Globalize2 gem, but not sure as to whether it is fully supported in Rails3.

Also found the [gem puret](https://github.com/jo/puret), which seems to have more recent commits/activity.

All in all though, it's very likely I am missing out on other possible options, as still getting my bearings in RoR dev.

Open to any info/suggestions you may have! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try gem named `has_translations`. It have been tested in several production sites for a one year already. Supports 1.9 + Rails 3. For any issues fill out form on the github.

https://github.com/dmitry/has_translations

Actually it's more or less the same as puret, but it was built when rails 2.3.5 was a mainstream, so I just supported it for a websites I've did already. I suggest you to choose between `puret` and `has_translations`, others is too magic or not maintained anymore. You can find more alternatives in `has_translations` README file.